# custom plugin bombing Edit Order page when trying wc_get_order

Tags: woocommerce

I'm writing a tiny custom plugin to add a meta box so I can freely interface with EasyPost.  It's included in the Edit Order page.  I'm trying to use wc_get_order to get basic order details and the page is bombing.  This looks like it should work flawlessly and be very simple, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

I'm using this code in:
/wp-content/plugins/custom-easypost/jens-custom-easypost.php

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I'm stumped.
This code is NOT WORKING:

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
```

This code IS working:

```
// Add meta box
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'jens_epbox' );
function jens_epbox() {
    add_meta_box(
        'jens-epbox-modal',
        'Jens EP Box',
        'jens_meta_box_callback',
        'shop_order',
        'side',
        'high'
    );
}

// Callback
function jens_meta_box_callback( $post )
{
      echo '<a href="">Get Label ' . $post->ID. '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Where you are trying to use this code, in what hooked function… please add the related code to get the context…

Comment: updated with more info.  it's not in a hooked function.  I'm just trying to access the order data.  I know that I'm a noob, please just point me in the right direction.  Thanks!

Comment: i think you answered my question!  I put it into a hooked function and it worked.

Comment: Lol … of course :) or it will work with an existing order id like `$order = wc_get_order( 851 );` where `851` is an existing order ID…